# I am fine tuning BLIP Image Captioning on ROCO dataset

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, computer-vision, huggingface-transformers

My train dataset contain 1800 images. I am using batch size of only 8 due to limitation of my memory. I am training it on Google Colab Pro. Increasing it from 8 throws Out of memory error. I have initially trained it for 10 epochs. The losses looks fine even on validation dataset. I have also shared the last epochs result

I am following below process:

```
from PIL import Image
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class ImageCaptioningDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, processor, max_image_size=100):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.processor = processor
        self.max_image_size = max_image_size

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataframe)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = self.dataframe.iloc[idx]
        image_path = item["image"]
        labels = item["label"]

        # Load and preprocess the image
        image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
        image = image.resize((self.max_image_size, self.max_image_size), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # Convert labels to string (adjust this step based on your label format)
        text = str(labels)

        encoding = self.processor(images=image, text=text, padding="max_length", return_tensors="pt")
        # remove batch dimension
        encoding = {k: v.squeeze() for k, v in encoding.items()}
        return encoding
```

```
from transformers import AutoProcessor, BlipForConditionalGeneration

processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-large")
model = BlipForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-large")

model.train()
```

```
train_dataset = ImageCaptioningDataset(dataframe=df, processor=processor)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=8)

val_dataset = ImageCaptioningDataset(dataframe=df_val, processor=processor)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=8)
```

```
import torch

optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
model.to(device)

for epoch in range(10):
    print("Epoch:", epoch)
    for idx, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        input_ids = batch.pop("input_ids").to(device)
        pixel_values = batch.pop("pixel_values").to(device)

        outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids,
                        pixel_values=pixel_values,
                        labels=input_ids)

        loss = outputs.loss

        print("Loss:", loss.item())

        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()


    # Validation
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        total_loss = 0
        total_samples = 0
        for idx, batch in enumerate(val_dataloader):
            input_ids = batch.pop("input_ids").to(device)
            pixel_values = batch.pop("pixel_values").to(device)

            outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, pixel_values=pixel_values, labels=input_ids)
            loss = outputs.loss

            total_loss += loss.item()
            total_samples += input_ids.size(0)

        avg_val_loss = total_loss / total_samples
        print("Validation Loss:", avg_val_loss)
```

The last epoch result is:

```
Epoch: 9
Loss: 1.4171884059906006
Loss: 1.4414808750152588
Loss: 1.437009334564209
Loss: 1.4208693504333496
Loss: 1.4376342296600342
.....
.....
.....
Loss: 1.448195219039917
Loss: 1.4534223079681396
Loss: 1.4529722929000854
Loss: 1.4163848161697388
Loss: 1.517378807067871
Loss: 1.4786649942398071
Loss: 1.4230802059173584
Validation Loss: 0.1795918705713683
```

But still on testing, every image is returning same caption. The train data all has unique captions. But I don't understand if the training is going fine which is tested with validation as well. Then why this is happening.

```
Image Path: PMC2829594_1752-1947-4-10-4.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion.
Image Path: PMC529466_1477-7819-2-36-1.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion.
Image Path: PMC125313_cc1496-1.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion.
Image Path: PMC280706_1477-7819-1-24-1.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion.
Image Path: PMC2440391_1752-1947-2-212-2.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion.
Image Path: PMC2848035_1749-8090-5-12-3.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion.
Image Path: PMC2700440_ATM-03-108-g001.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion.
Image Path: PMC2542347_1757-1626-1-122-1.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion.
Image Path: PMC2727506_1749-8090-4-40-1.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion with a small
Image Path: PMC2783120_1757-1626-2-164-1.jpg
Generated Caption: chest x - ray showing a large right - sided pleural effusion.
```

Please guide what I am doing wrong here. How can I improve this?

Thanks!